# how to initiate a node js command with a html button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

i am making a PWA for my college portal, so i need an API for HTTPS call, but unfortunately i have no API for that website which i am making for to use the concepts like FETCH API in js or AXIOS. I would rather go with XMLHTTPS request but, its an old one and very complex too. So, i though of using selenium with javascript. and i did it successfully, just installed npm package and i have installed some webdrivers for firefox.and everything is fine, but the whole selenium webdriver is working with a node command.

```
node file_name
```

node file_name.js
any syntax is accepted .

```js
 const {Builder, By, Key, util}=require("selenium-webdriver");
async function example(){
   let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();
   await driver.get("https://login.gitam.edu/Login.aspx"); //this is the link
   await driver.findElement(By.name("txtusername")).sendKeys("0116", Key.INSERT);
   await driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password", Key.RETURN);
}
example();
```

now, the above code is operated by `node file_name`

but i need this from my UI , Which i am making for my PWA. so, i design button, when user click that, it is going to initiate the above selenium javascript snippet.So i need a code or any resource for making that button to initiate the terminal command and that in return makes selenium javascript code to run.
please answer my question.
ps: this is my first question on stackoverflow !!!!
thank you very much.

Comment: You will need to create a `Node.js` server that exposes an `API` endpoint which triggers this function when an `HTTP` request is sent from your `client-side` code after the button is clicked.

Comment: is there any other way to do it ? because i am not much into this scripting, which i am not good at node js or js. so if you can elaborate me , it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: That'd be the proper way to do it. You want to trigger some function on the backend based on user action on the frontend. Look up how to create a `Node.js` server that exposes `API` endpoints.